# Microsoft Excel Price Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am doing a formula that takes a cost x a mark up % to get a sell price.

$11.47 x 1.35 = $15.48.  I then need to go and copy and paste values to remove the mark up for my customers.  When I do this, it gives me $15.4845 which throws off my lot dollars.  Is there anyway to mark this to only calculate to 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 3):

Change the number format of the cells to $0.00 or in your formula use the worksheet function ROUND(number, decimal places).

So your formula would change from:

```
=(G9*$G$1)
```

to

```
=ROUND(G9*$G$1, 2)
```

Comment: The first option will change the way the number looks without changing the value, the second will change the actual value.

Comment: Where in my formula would I put the function?  Here is what my formula looks like:  (G9*$G$1)